# Circuit Protection - Difference between two gas discharged tubes that are spec'd the same?

Tags: circuit-protection

http://www.digikey.com/product-search/compare/en?returnUrl=%2Fproduct-search%2Fen%3FFV%3D90c000e%26k%3DGDT%2B500V%2B20%2525%2B5KA%2BTHROUGH%2BHOLE%26mnonly%3D0%26newproducts%3D0%26ColumnSort%3D-1000011%26page%3D1%26stock%3D0%26pbfree%3D0%26rohs%3D0%26quantity%3D%26ptm%3D0%26fid%3D0%26pageSize%3D25&part=495-1476-ND&part=GTCA26-501M-R05-ND

We are looking at protection for our new design. Upon doing BOM reduction exercises we discovered EC90X gas discharge tubes are $1.79 (Digikey Part Number 495-1476-ND). The ones marked new are $.50 and spec'd the same (Digikey Part Number GTCA26-501M-R05-ND). Can anyone find reasons why not to go to the 50 cent ones?

We also parallel a TVS SMAJ51CA in with the gas discharge tube.

[image]

Comment: A Digikey comparison is the 50,000 ft. view. Compare the datasheets to be sure they're the same. They're probably just two competing products.

Comment: Agreed and in the process. I couldn't attach the files to here. Or can I??

Comment: Anyway, just looking for experts and more of the community to chime in on the datasheets also!

Answer (score 1):

I would be concerned because the datasheet that digikey points to says 90V DC spark-over while digikey's description says 90V for the EPCOS device. So if we go based on the datasheet for the EPCOS component and compare it to the TE that you show the DC spark-over is now 500V which means that your device might have to withstand the higher voltage. However, in the same TE datasheet it shows the  GTCX26-900M-R05 part with an 90V DC spark-over that might be more appropriate. At this point I would contact EPCOS and Digikey and find out the actual DC spark-over voltage device since there seems to be a discrepancy.

Comment: Isnt this where the TVS diode window comes into play in parallel.

Comment: <http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?KeyWords=SMAJ51CA&WT.z_header=search_go>

Those are the TVS that are in parallel. I am picking up this design and just getting the chance to research. Greatly value everyone's input. Thanks!

Comment: Digikey said "Brett_ext_1581: The 90V will be in a constant voltage state. The 500V is for the impulse that it is more likely to see as a GDT."

Comment: SON OF A!!! "After talking with the group that puts the information on the website it appears the wrong number was taking and put in the information.  They will be fixing this and putting the correct nominal DC spark over voltage of 90V for 495-1476-ND."